# Configure Jenkins with AD without password Authentication

Tags: jenkins, active-directory

Currently, we are integrating AD with jenkins where we are using a user id which has non-expiry password for authentication.

We are asked not to use any userids for authentication the AD configuration. Is there any other way where we can connect to AD by giving the AD Server details or SAML without using any user id for authentication purpose to connect with AD.

Thanks in advance.

We have tried with password authentication with the userid to AD but need a alternative solution(not use password for AD configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Use [the NegotiateSSO plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/NegotiateSSO/) and ensure to go through the documentation. It will autologin the user on a connected computer.